# jQuery load() not passing complete string in url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that takes a country name and passes it to a processing page via the load() function.

In the following example the country is "American Samoa"

```
function loadRates(oArg) {
        var Destination = oArg.Destination.toString() || '';
        alert(Destination); // Alerts "American Samoa"
        var uniqueid = new Date().getTime();
        $('#divRates2').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif">').load('inc_rates_output.cfm?Destination=' + Destination + '&uniqueid=' + uniqueid);
    }
```

However, the processing page (inc_rates_output.cfm) receives the Destination url variable as "American", i.e. without the "Samoa".

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Try to use `encodeURIComponent` on `Destination` before adding it to the url.  `load('inc_rates_output.cfm?Destination=' + encodeURIComponent(Destination) + `

Comment: You should probably URL encode your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'encodeURI(Destination)'` in url.

The specification for URLs ([RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), Dec. '94) poses a problem, in that it limits the use of allowed characters in URLs to only a limited subset of the US-ASCII character set:

> ...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters
>   "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters
>   used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
you can pass your parameters to load as an object, and let jquery do the encoding for you.

```
function loadRates(oArg) {
        var Destination = oArg.Destination.toString() || '';
        alert(Destination); // Alerts "American Samoa"
        var uniqueid = new Date().getTime();
        $('#divRates2').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif">').load('inc_rates_output.cfm', {"Destination" : Destination, "uniqueid" : uniqueid});
    }
```

Comment: I'm intrigued by this, but how does the receiving page see this object in order to use it?

Comment: jquery will turn your object into something your receiving page can use.  if you pass it as an object, it'll send the request as a POST, and your parameters will be post variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `Destination` to escape function

`escape(Destination)`